# What is the meaning of "I cosay"?

Tags: search

Search the web for the phrase "I cosay".  I run across this phrase being used from time to time by individuals in tech forums, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what it means or how it makes sense in the context of the conversations where it is used.

Am I just way behind the times?  New slang?

Comment: @splattne: how do you know this is not a programming-related question if you don't know the answer to it?

Comment: "Question closed as "not programming related" by splattne 14 secs ago" - how do you know it's not programming related? - and if you do, why didn't you answer the question with the non-programming related answer, then close it, that'd have been more helpful..  :o)

Comment: Steven and Andrew, why do you assume I don't know the answer? Okay, if you like, let's bring a little http://www.urbandictionary.com/ to StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: Note to myself: never close a question again. There will always be people who are interested in it. ;-)

Comment: @splattne: urbandictionary.com has no defition for cosay. Nice try.

Comment: Steven, here is a new question for SO: "What is the meaning of defition? - Run across this phrase being used from time to time by individuals in tech forums, but I cannot figure out what it means or how it makes sense in the context of the conversations where it is used." - Just kidding...

Comment: @splattne: never heard of "defition", perhaps yahoo answers can help you ;-)

Comment: Steven, your words: "urbandictionary.com has no defition for cosay. Nice try." ;-) - PS: I have to admit - the answer to this question was worth reopening it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the contexts Google pulls up, it is a very poorly machine-translated form of "codigo".  "digo" or some variant is "I say", so it forms it as "I cosay" when it really shouldn't be translated at all.  Roughly translated it should probably be "code" or "encoding".

Comment: I agree with David B. I see alot of foreign (bad english) with the saying. So far it is mostly coming from a French and Spanish translation.

Comment: The very first link I get from a google search for "i cosay" is: 'Resumo de I Cosay Gives Vinci (el Codigo Da Vinci) - Brown, Dan'. This is, of course, everyone's favorite religious conspiracy work, The Da Vinci Code. (Da can also mean 'give' in Spanish.)

Comment: Yes, I believe that this is the correct answer.  Codigo being translated from Spanish as "I co-say" rather than just "code".  Good one!

Comment: Here's one in context, and the page even says it was machine-translated...  http://en.programacionweb.net/articulos/articulo/?num=106

Answer (score 9):

It's pig latin for Psycho.

Comment: Ooklay it up on Ikipediaway if it doesn't make ensesay... :)

Answer (score 0):

Without context, I'll have to say a cosay is the counter-say in the same vein that cosine is a counter to sine.

Answer (score 0):

from the context of usage it looks like slang for agreement - you say X and I cosay X - possibly invented by non-native english speakers - but that does not cover all of the contexts of usage...

Answer (score 0):

In french from Quebec (not France) it means : "I do not understand what you are talking about, can you repeat?" but it's a very low level of language... nothing official and shouldn't be used ... often kid use that type of expression...